# VS2010 Editing Stylesheet - The Operation Could Not Be Completed. Unspecified Error

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Recently I noticed when I am using VS2010 to create a web application and I add a stylesheet to the solution that I am unable to open the stylesheet using vs2010 default css editor.

I tried to perform a repair which made no difference. Looking back, the problem started about the time I loaded the standards patch for HTML 5.

Any hints or ideas how to address this issue?

Thanks
Ray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably VS 2010 got corrupted. Reinstall.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/vssetup/thread/e505875a-0b74-4d46-987b-e376f958b9bc

Answer (score 4):

Web Standards Update for Visual Studio 2010 SP1 caused the issue for me. Had to uninstall

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this.  I installed the "CSS 3 Intellisense Schema" extension, started VS2010 and went to work on an MVC4 project.  I ran into the "really slow typing" bug while editing razor views, so I decided I would try uninstalling the CSS3 extension.  After starting VS2010 again, I could not open CSS files.  What I figured out was that the CSS validation was set to "CSS 3.0" in VS2010 when I uninstalled the extension and the editor was still trying to use that schema.

This fixed it for me:

1. Install the "CSS 3 Intellisense Schema" extension
2. Start VS2010 and open a stylesheet
3. Go to View->Toolbars and enable "Style Sheet" toolbar
4. In the toolbar that appears, change the CSS version shown in the dropdown to an older version (I used "CSS 2.1")
5. Close VS2010 and *uninstall* the CSS3 extension once again

Hope this helps someone.  Visual Studio wastes far too much of my time these days.