# VS2010 The operation could not be completed

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I got following error while opening stylesheet in vs2010:

> The operation could not be completed

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638903/vs2010-editing-stylesheet-the-operation-could-not-be-completed-unspecified-er), I re-installed VS2010 but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7272955/1154184

Comment: @Reyno post as answer so we can upvote you and get marked as answer. :D

Comment: @djIT Glad it worked for you. Posted :)

Comment: @Reyno, my pleasure to have ur right ans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7272955/1154184) :

> go to the Tools -> Extension Manager -> Online Gallery and search for/install the "Web Standards Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010