# The operation could not completed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6

I have created new MVC web application in visual studio with Individual account. Every functionality is working fine including Identity and sql localDB.

But when I add entity framework into my project. It giving me error in dialog box. "The operation could not completed". In output window i saw

> TF10121: The path '\\D:\c#\2016\testdelete\testdelete\Data\Model1.edmx.diagram' is not found or not supported. Type or select a different path.

I googled it but everybody giving different solution and those are not working.

I re-install my visual studio, but same error.

Do I need to change any path to solve this issue ?

I have created new solution from scratch, and there is only one project.

**Tried with below solutions,**

[VS2010 The operation could not be completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14871616/vs2010-the-operation-could-not-be-completed)
Installed mentioned package. (ASPNET WEB FRAMEWORK TOOL)

Visual studio was suggested me to install "AspNet5.ENU.RC1_Update1_KB3137909", and I installed this too.

I am using latest EF.

I tried to remove project and created new project as mentioned here,
http://chrisghardwick.blogspot.in/2011/12/tf10121-path-is-not-found-or-not.html

Comment: What solutions posted over the net have you tried? Can you list all of them? Can you add EF to any other solution, or have you tried to recreate the solution from scratch by adding individual projects? Also, I don't like that the path starts with `\\`, but it may be irrelevant.

Comment: You might have a look at my answer regarding to this problem on **[Visual Studio Hosting Process and “The operation could not be completed”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338/visual-studio-hosting-process-and-the-operation-could-not-be-completed/50497064#50497064)**.